# Optimize $\begin{align} \min _{ (x_1,..,x_n) }\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n e^{-\frac{(x_i-x_k)^2}{2}} \end{align}$ such that $|x_i|\le a$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Does the following optimization problem have a solution? For some fixed $n \ge 1$ and $a>0$
\begin{align}
 \min _{ (x_1,..,x_n) }\sum_{i=1}^n  \sum_{k=1}^n  e^{-\frac{(x_i-x_k)^2}{2}}
\end{align}
subject to a constraint 
\begin{align}
|x_i| \le a, \forall i\in \{1,...,n\}
\end{align}

For the case of $n=1$  the optimization problem is trivial since the valu is always $1$.

For $n=2$

\begin{align}
2 +2  \min_{(x_1,x_2)}e^{-\frac{(x_1-x_2)^2}{2}}
\end{align}

Then the optimal solution is to take $x_1=-a$ and $x_2=a$.

It seems that the points must spread as far as possible. But I am not sure if the optimal solution is $(-a,a,-b,b,...,-c,c,)$.

Comment: You should say, as you are a little accustomed to this SE site, what you have already tried ! Have you for example considered elementary cases $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=3$ and see what happens ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. I added a few examples.

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange multipliers ?

Comment: This problem *does have* a solution because your are minimizing a continuous function over a compact set.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM No, I haven't. I don't even know how to start applying Lagrangians to this problem.

Comment: The problem is that your constraint $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq a$ is not differentiable so you might have to consider the Lagrange multiplier for subdifferential.

Comment: @Surb can't you rewrite it with $2n$ inequalities ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM you can :) and it is probably much easier

Comment: Dinking around in MATLAB, it sure looks like
$
x_i = (-1)^ia
$
minimizes the sum.

Comment: @TLDavis Thanks. Any idea how to solve it in general.

Comment: @Lisa The Lagrangian approach is messy on paper. Have you covered some convexity results in your course ? (things like duality for example)

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM No, I haven't . But  if you put a solution I will try to follow.  I am very curios what the solution to this problem is.

Comment: Another thought, since $e^{-\frac{(x_i-x_k)^2}{2}}\geq 1-(x_i-x_k)^2$, it may be relevant to try and solve $$\max _{ (x_1,..,x_n) }\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n (x_i-x_k)^2$$, noting that the objective function rewrites more simply as $$ 2n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2\left( \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2$$ but even that seems difficult.

Comment: By the way, is it a research problem, an olympiad problem, a textbook problem ?

Comment: Last comment, you're actually looking at the Gaussian kernel distance between $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ on the real line (see [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~jeffp/papers/gentleintroKD.pdf))

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I believe that solving the maximization problem you mentioned is actually equivalent as $t \mapsto e^{-t/2}$ is a decreasing function.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I was reading a paper for my MS thesis research.  The authors were simply evaluating this function. I thought they can do better if  they optimize. But I see now why they didn't optimize.

Comment: @Surb Can you elaborate why it is so?

Answer (score 1):

(*The following is a comment on the $n=3$ case, though too long to post as an actual comment*.)

Solution(s) must exist, since the sum is a continuous function on a compact set, as noted in the comments already. However, the *pattern* of the solutions will likely depend on the range of $a\,$.

In the $n=3$ case the double sum is $S(x_1,x_2,x_3)=3+2\Big(e^{- \frac{(x_1-x_2)^2}{2}}+e^{- \frac{(x_2-x_3)^2}{2}}+e^{- \frac{(x_3-x_1)^2}{2}}\Big)\,$. Let $T = \frac{S-3}{2}=e^{- \frac{(x_1-x_2)^2}{2}}+e^{- \frac{(x_2-x_3)^2}{2}}+e^{- \frac{(x_3-x_1)^2}{2}}\,$, which varies directly monotonically with $S$.

Assume WLOG that $-a \le x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le a\,$. Then "shifting" $x_3$ to $a$ increases both $x_3-x_2$ and $x_3-x_1\,$, thus decreases $T$. Similarly, shifting $x_1$ to $-a$ further decreases $T$. Therefore, the minimum of $T$ must be attained at some $x \in [-a,a]$ which minimizes:

$$
T- e^{- 2a^2}=f(x)=e^{- \frac{(x+a)^2}{2}}+e^{- \frac{(x-a)^2}{2}}
$$

Since $f$ is an even function, the minimum on $[-a,a]$ is the same as the minimum on $[0,a]\,$, and it can only be attained either at the ends of the interval, or otherwise inside it at a local minimum.

Leaving potential local minimums aside, the values at the ends of the interval are $f(0)=2 e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}$ and $f(a)=1+e^{-2a^2}\,$, respectively, and they coincide for [$a_0 \simeq 1.104\cdots$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Be%5E(-2a%5E2)%3D2%20e%5E(-a%5E2%2F2)) (which can be determined in closed form, per the "*exact forms*" option in the previous link). For $a \lt a_0$ the minimum appears to be attained at [$\,x=a\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%20e%5E(-(x-1.1)%5E2%2F2)%2Be%5E(-(x%2B1.1)%5E2%2F2)%20for%20x%20in%20%5B-1.1,1.1%5D) i.e. $\,S(-a,\pm a,a)\,$, while for $\,a \gt a_0\,$ it is at [$\,x=0\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%20e%5E(-(x-1.2)%5E2%2F2)%2Be%5E(-(x%2B1.2)%5E2%2F2)%20for%20x%20in%20%5B-1.2,1.2%5D) i.e. $\,S(-a,0,a)\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  The above hints (though doesn't prove) that for $n=3$ and $a \le a_0$ the sum $S_3$ is minimized when $x_{1,2,3}$ are split between the endpoints $\pm a$ of the allowed range.

Assuming this result, a good case could be made (though, again, not a proof) that for $n \gt 3$ *and* $a \le a_0$ the sum $S_n$ is minimized when $x_k$ are evenly split $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ between the endpoints $\pm a\,$. The idea is to iteratively "shift" one of the $n$ points to either endpoint $\pm a$ while showing that $S_n$ decreases at each step, which means that the end configuration is at least a local minimum.

Like in the base case, assume WLOG that $(x_k)$ are sorted ascendingly within $[-a,a]\,$. Then...

- Shifting the largest value $x_n$ to $a$ increases all $x_n-x_i$ for $i \lt n\,$, thus decreases $S_n$.
- Shifting the smallest value $x_1$ to $-a$ increases all $x_i-x_1$ for $i \gt 1\,$, thus decreases $S_n$.
- Shifting the next largest value $x_{n-1}$ to $a$ increases all $x_{n-1}-x_i$ for $1 \lt i \lt n-1\,$, and by the $n=3$ hypothesis it also decreases $S_3(x_1=-a,x_{n-1},x_n=a)$, so in the end it decreases $S_n\,$.
- Shifting the next smallest value $x_2$ to $-a$ increases all $x_i-x_2$ for $2 \lt i \lt n\,$, and it also decreases $S_3(x_1=-a,x_2,x_n=a)$, so in the end it decreases $S_n$ as well.
- Shifting now $x_{n-2}$ to $a$ increases all $x_{n-2}-x_i$ for $2 \lt i \lt n-2\,$, and the rest of terms in $S_n$ add up to $2 \cdot S_3(-a,x_{n-2},a)\,$ which also decreases.
- $\cdots$

The process can be repeated until all points have been evenly "shifted" to the two endpoints.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice and comprehensive "comment". Any chance that these ideas are extendable to $n>3$.

Comment: @Lisa I *think* the case $a \le a_0$ can be extended to $n \gt 3\,$, see the new "comment".