# Solve $\min_{ x_1,...,x_n} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{c_i x_i}$ s.t. $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \le a$

Tags: calculus, optimization

How to minimize
\begin{align}
\min_{ x_1,...,x_n} \prod_{i=1}^n  \frac{1}{c_i x_i}
\end{align}
where $c_i \ge 0$ and $x_i \ge 0$.

Subject to the Ecleadian norm on $\{x_i\}$ that is
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \le a. 
\end{align}

Comment: @dxiv  My bad. I wanted to say that $x_i$ are are positive

Comment: Hint: maximize $\prod x_i$.

Comment: @dxiv   Can you explain more. I see that $ \min \frac{1}{c_i x_i}=\frac{1}{\max \prod_{i=1}^n c_i x_i }$. But how to proceed next?

Comment: @dxiv Can you help me out. I am not sure how to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\;\;\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \le \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^n \le \left(\frac{a^2}{n}\right)^n\,$ by AM-GM, with equality iff all $x_i$ are equal. Then:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n  \frac{1}{c_i x_i} = \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n c_i} \cdot  \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i} = \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n c_i} \cdot  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^2}} \ge \;\cdots
$$

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if you can take a look at the question I asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186827/optimize-beginalign-min-x-1-x-n-sum-i-1n-sum-k-1n-e-fra?rq=1

Comment: @Lisa Glad it helped. The other problem is interesting, though I don't have a good idea offhand.

Comment: Dear @dxiv perhaps you can take a look at this question that I recently posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240910/set-of-on-which-a-certain-function-is-negative?noredirect=1#comment4607677_2240910